# Is it possible to construct probability theory which is not based on measure theory but on logic?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

A probability space is a triplet $(\Omega, F, P)$, where $\Omega$ is a set, $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ and $P$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega, F)$.

However, do we need $\Omega$?

What if we define as follows:

- A **probability set** $G$ is a set of propositions which satisfies

  1. $\bot \in G$
  2. If $p \in G$, then $\lnot p \in G$
  3. If $p_1, p_2, \dots \in G$, then $\lor_{i=1}^\infty p_i \in G$
- A **probalitiy function** $P$ is a function from $G$ to $[0, 1]$ which satisfies

  1. $P(\top)=1$
  2. $P(\lor_{i=1}^\infty p_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(p_i)$ if $p_i \land p_j$ is false when $i \neq j$

Comment: A summation of proposition symbols??...

Comment: @drhab I edited.

Comment: The title seems unrelated to the question.

Comment: @Sambo I want to know whether probability theory should be based on measure theory. I think logic can be used instead of measurable space.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. But the title still isn't very suggestive: it doesn't mention your idea of using logic instead. Also, "do we need measure theory to do probability" could be answered "no", since most first probability classes dispense of mentioning measure theory explicitly (this was my first thought when reading your title).

Comment: What you need is a Boolean algebra with special property that it has countable joins. That corresponds with a space that is equipped with a $\sigma$-algebra according to the representation theorem of Stone. So there is no essential difference. Further  $\Omega  $ is replaced by truth-symbol, so we still need/use it.

Comment: @Sambo Measure theory can be avoided uptil discrete random variables. When continuous random variables come in it starts knocking at the door: "let me in too!...".

Comment: @drhab Haha admittedly! I still think the title could be clearer, though.

Comment: @Sambo I changed the title.

Comment: Thank you :) I do think your question is very interesting!

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  If you think about it, you need $\Omega$ and $P$ first. Or else for a given $p\in\Omega$, $\neg p$ does not make sense.  Since $$\neg p = \{q\in\Omega | q \neq p\}$$
The $\sigma$-algebra $F$ is in some sense "What events in $\Omega$ satisfy conditions of $P$"

Comment: The asker is using propositions in their definition. In that case $\neg p$ is perfectly valid without needing $\Omega$; it is not a set.

Comment: So it seems to me, in the language of measure theory, that the asker's probability set $G$ is exactly the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra $F$.  So to map it onto measure theory, it would be the special case $\Omega =F$

Comment: The set $G$ does behave similarly to a $\sigma$-algebra, but its elements are not sets. "$\neg p$" is not a collection of elements which are not equal to $p$, it is the proposition which is the negation of $p$.